# Django rest framework умеет отдавать html страницу?

Tags: framework, javascript, html, rest, django

Или быть может есть другая библиотека дающая подобный функционал

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Умеет. Смотрите в сторону [TemplateHTMLRenderer](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers.html#templatehtmlrenderer). У Response есть аттрибут [template_name](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/responses.html#template_name)